# MRTK Spatial Awareness Mesh Color is NULL

Tags: hololens, mrtk

When I get the Meshes from SpatialAwarenessMeshObserver, I found the Mesh.Colors is NULL.Can I get the color of real world through MTRK?

Answer (score 0):

The triangle meshes provided by SpatialAwareness only representing the geometry of the environment, and the actual color cannot be sampled.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can I get the actual color from other way？

Comment: Please take a look [Research Mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/research-mode), the [Stream Recorder sample](https://github.com/microsoft/HoloLens2ForCV/tree/main/Samples/StreamRecorder) provides an approach may meet your needs. In short, you need to capture Long-throw depth frames, RGB frames and head poses, and then compute all the point clouds from depth images and try to color the point clouds to correlate them in a common coordinate frame.